# Keeping one parameter fixed and search on randomly in caret

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet, lasso-regression

I would like to keep the parameter alpha fixed at 1 and use random search for lambda, is this possible?

```
library(caret)

X <- iris[, 1:4]
Y <- iris[, 5]

fit_glmnet <- train(X, Y, method = "glmnet", tuneLength = 2, trControl = trainControl(search = "random"))
```

Comment: `glmnet` will create a sequence of `lambda` values on its own and test them. Just set `alpha = 1` and `glmnet` will look for the best lambda.

Comment: Where in caret train call can do I set this? I get the following: formal argument "alpha" matched by multiple actual argument. If I set it in the train function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think this can be achieved by specifying directly in caret `train` but here is how to emulate the desired behavior:

From this [link](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/glmnet.R)

one can see random search for lambda is achieved by:

```
lambda = 2^runif(len, min = -10, 3)
```

where `len` is the tune length

To emulate random search over one parameter:

```
len <- 2
fit_glmnet <- train(X, Y,
                    method = "glmnet",
                    tuneLength = len,
                    trControl = trainControl(search = "grid"),
                    tuneGrid = data.frame(alpha = 1, lambda = 2^runif(len, min = -10, 3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'm not sure you can use a random search *and* fix specific tuning parameters.

However, as an alternative you could use a grid search for optimising tuning parameters instead of a random search. You can then fix tuning parameters using `tuneGrid`:

```
fit <- train(
    X,
    Y,
    method = "glmnet",
    tuneLength = 2,
    trControl = trainControl(search = "grid"),
    tuneGrid = data.frame(alpha = 1, lambda = 10^seq(-4, -1, by = 0.5)));
 fit;
 #glmnet
 #
 #150 samples
 #  4 predictor
 #  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'
 #
 #No pre-processing
 #Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps)
 #Summary of sample sizes: 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, ...
 #Resampling results across tuning parameters:
 #
 #  lambda        Accuracy   Kappa
 #  0.0001000000  0.9398036  0.9093246
 #  0.0003162278  0.9560817  0.9336278
 #  0.0010000000  0.9581838  0.9368050
 #  0.0031622777  0.9589165  0.9379580
 #  0.0100000000  0.9528997  0.9288533
 #  0.0316227766  0.9477923  0.9212374
 #  0.1000000000  0.9141015  0.8709753
 #
 #Tuning parameter 'alpha' was held constant at a value of 1
 #Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
 #The final values used for the model were alpha = 1 and lambda = 0.003162278.
```

Comment: Fully aware I could use above approach, but I looking for a answering if I can use random search and fix one parameter...

Comment: @MLEN Yeah, I wasn't sure whether the random search was the critical requirement in your question;-) I'm afraid I can't help with that (other than I think it's not possible). Perhaps somebody else is able to shed some light onto this...